# how to remove silence periods from wav file in python?

Tags: python, audio, silent, pydub

I have a conversation in wav file (customer service) I split it to 2 audio channels. Now I have 2 wav files and each person is speaking and it has silence periods. I need to cut out those silent periods to "compress" all one's persons words in shorter file.

I googled and found this [link](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/89505/pydub.AudioSegment.from_wav).
It has this code:

```
def addFrameWithTransition(self, image_file, audio_file, transition_file):
    media_info = MediaInfo.parse(transition_file)
    duration_in_ms = media_info.tracks[0].duration
    audio_file = audio_file.replace("\\", "/")
    try:
        audio_clip = AudioSegment.from_wav(r"%s"%audio_file)
        f = sf.SoundFile(r"%s"%audio_file)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        audio_clip = AudioSegment.from_wav("%s/pause.wav" % settings.assetPath)
        f = sf.SoundFile("%s/pause.wav" % settings.assetPath)
    duration = (len(f) / f.samplerate)
    audio_clip_with_pause = audio_clip
    self.imageframes.append(image_file)
    self.audiofiles.append(audio_clip_with_pause)
    self.durations.append(duration)
    self.transitions.append((transition_file, len(self.imageframes) - 1, duration_in_ms / 1000))
```

But it needs some kind of 'image file'. any other options?

Comment: How do you define silence? Is it period without ANY sound below certain threshold or lack of voice?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski lack of voice

Comment: https://github.com/pradbajaj/bothoven/blob/master/sound.py. This is for detecting silence and taking those part where the sound is and finding the frequency nodes

Answer (score 1):

i found a small vad.py file that splits a conversation into two and actually compresses each voice track. 
In the end you will have 2 wav files with only 1 person speaking.

https://github.com/mauriciovander/silence-removal/blob/master/vad.py

works like this:

```
python vad name_of_new_file.wav
```

Comment: The code you shared is not, despite the name, voice activity detector (VAD). It's a crude  "activity" detector that will be triggered by any noise, not just voice, that goes beyond threshold.